# How do I wire my dishwasher and disposal back to my house wiring?

Tags: electrical, dishwasher, garbage-disposal

I lost the diagram I had when I took this circuit apart and I am having trouble trying to get it back together.  Disposal and dishwasher, each on a separate breaker.  Have 2 hots and a neutral coming up from basement.  Disposal has switch on wall and there are another two wires headed that direction.  When I turn either of the breakers on, both of the hots set off my non contact tester which is making it difficult for me to figure out which is supposed to be which.  No outlet involved, was all direct wired.

[image: picture of wiring]

Orange and yellow on the left are the two headed towards the switch.  Black and yellow coming towards the camera are the 2 hot wires, white I assume is a neutral.  Romex on the right is dishwasher, coming in from the top is the disposal

Comment: We'll need a clear diagram of what wires you have and where they are. A few clear pics would work as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, let's see if I can make this clear:

White from feed spliced to both whites from the romex cables.

Yellow from feed to yellow from switch.

Orange from switch to black from disposal.

Black from feed to black from DW.

Be sure to splice all grounds and a ground tail to the box, and put a blank cover on the box.